# Can't convert varchar into date using sas data integation studio

Tags: oracle, sas, sas-dis

I am new using sas data Integartion Studio 4.9005.  i am using database oracle 18.

the scenario is i move from table_A with data type varchar(100) to table_B with date data type.

the format from table_A is YYYY/MM/DD
[image]

but the result is give me random number (01-01-1960) it doesn't make sense.

[image]

for code to convert is "INPUT( TANGGAL_LAHIR  ,yymmdd10.)"

[image]

Is there i am missing ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure the target field is DATE and not DATETIME.  Any reasonable DATE value (number of days) would be early in the morning of 01JAN1960 if treated as a DATETIME value (number of seconds).

Comment: yes, i am sure the destination table ( target field ) have data type DATE

Comment: But is it an ORACLE table?  I don't think ORACLE actually has DATE type.  Just DATETIME types that only display the DATE part.  At least that is what I have seen happening to me in the past.  What happens if you query the result and display it with a DATETIME format? Does it include a time of day?

Comment: Try using ANYDTDTM10. as the INFORMAT in your conversion. That will convert YYYY/MM/DD strings into number of seconds instead of number of days.

Comment: Also watch out for leading spaces in your source VARCHAR field.  A lot of SAS displays will not show the leading spaces, but the INPUT() function will not ignore them.  Try `INPUT(left(TANGGAL_LAHIR) ,yymmdd10.)`

Comment: @user3698988 You cut off the very right-most part of the important bit on the picture.  Is that a "T" after "DATE" on TANGAL_LAHIR?  Get a better part of that picture.  There are two possibilities here, both of which suggest you have some information wrong; this is the most likely.

Comment: Add a User_Written_Code step (the last one in the Data group) add the code `proc contents data=STG_TD_KJP; proc contents data=TD_KJP; run;` share us the result.